# Why do some users start with 100 rep, and others 1?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I haven't understood the pattern, but some folks seem to start with either 1 or 100 rep.  Can anyone explan why?

If you look at the "users" tab, sort by account age, then it seems very inconsistent, especially when trying to figure out the logic if it's based on other-site membership.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not at all a bug, very much by design:

> When you sign up, if you associate your account with your account on another SE/SOFU site with *at least 200 rep on the other site*, you automatically get an extra 100 points here too.

(or something like that, couldnt find the exact quote).

Comment: I'm associated with many sites (and so are others I spot checked.) I have over 100 rep on all of them...  If you look at the rep history, I started with zero and got 50 points the first day (though asking questions)...

Comment: @maker, and you have 200-300 rep on other site, before you joined?

Comment: Every other site I'm a part of is 100 or greater, but many are above 200.  I'm not sure which one needs to be equal to 200 or greater. On programmers and stackoverflow I have over 1,000.  That should qualify, right?

Comment: @maker, I dunno. I would think that's good enough, but ask @Jeff.

Comment: I must be confused.  I went to security.stackexchange.com/reputation and it all adds up.